# What does the -x and -c string comparison options do?

Tags: linux, string, bash, sh, hp-ux

I'm in the process of porting over another shell script when I came across the following:

```
if [[ ! -x $DVDREC ]]; then
  print "ERROR: $DVDREC not found. Exiting ..."
  exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -c ${DVDDEV} ]]; then
  print "ERROR: ${DVDDEV} not found. Exiting ..."
  exit 1
fi
```

I was wondering what the -c and -x options actually do with regards to the strings stored
in DVDREC and DVDDEV?

Answer (score 3):

From "help test" in a bash shell:

> ```
>   -c FILE        True if file is character special.
>   -x FILE        True if the file is executable by you.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

// man test

```
   -c FILE
          FILE exists and is character special

   -x FILE
          FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
```

Answer (score 3):

Citing `man test`:

> ```
>    -c FILE
>           FILE exists and is character special
>
>    -x FILE
>           FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm fairly new to the Linux Operating System so I wasn't aware that there was a manpage for test.

Comment: @Justin: No problems. For people who are new to bash the relationship between `[` and `test` is not obvious. So it's a good question.

Comment: @justin - the manpage isn't for the test command that you would be using. The `test` builtin or `[` would be used first. In your case, you are using a bash keyword `[[`, rather than a command. The flags are the same.